# Hero-slider shows slider functions but don't shows images

Tags: reactjs

I have a small app with react where I used hero-slider for the image slider. it shows the result as slider and background color. but the images are not shown.
here is my basicslider.js

```
import React from "react";
// JSX
import HeroSlider, { Slide, Nav } from "hero-slider";


// Images
const bogliasco = "https://i.imgur.com/Gu5Cznz.jpg";
const countyClare = "https://i.imgur.com/idjXzVQ.jpg";
const craterRock = "https://i.imgur.com/8DYumaY.jpg";
const giauPass = "https://i.imgur.com/8IuucQZ.jpg";

const BasicSlider = () => {
  return (
    <HeroSlider
      slidingAnimation="left_to_right"
      orientation="horizontal"
      initialSlide={1}
      onBeforeChange={(previousSlide, nextSlide) =>
        console.log("onBeforeChange", previousSlide, nextSlide)
      }
      onChange={nextSlide => console.log("onChange", nextSlide)}
      onAfterChange={nextSlide => console.log("onAfterChange", nextSlide)}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33)"
      }}
      settings={{
        slidingDuration: 250,
        slidingDelay: 100,
        shouldAutoplay: true,
        shouldDisplayButtons: true,
        autoplayDuration: 5000,
        height: "100vh"
      }}
    >

      <Slide
        background={{
          backgroundImage: giauPass,
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
        }}
      />

      <Slide
        background={{
          backgroundImage: bogliasco,
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
        }}
      />

      <Slide
        background={{
          backgroundImage: countyClare,
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
        }}
      />

      <Slide
        background={{
          backgroundImage: craterRock,
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
        }}
      />

      <Nav />
    </HeroSlider>
  );
};

export default BasicSlider;
```

Here is app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './app.css'
import BasicSlider from './containers/basicslider/BasicSlider';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BasicSlider/>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Everything is fine. No error. No warning. Just it shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TJtt.png)

I want to make the images visible. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add component as backgroundImage, the correct way:

```
<Slide
  background={{
     backgroundImageSrc: bogliasco,
     backgroundAttachment: "fixed"
  }}
/>
```